# Apply Caching Aspect to Camel Routes using InterceptFrom

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel, interceptor

I want to apply the caching aspect to Apache Camel Routes using InterceptFrom feature by intercepting
every incoming exchange in a route.

I am able to successfully load the RestDefinitions and RouteDefinitions currently from separate xml files.

In a similar way I want to load the Intercept definition from a seperate XML file.

I currently have tne following content in my xml(Intercept.xml) file which I use to load the InterceptFrom Definitions as below. I only log them as of now. i will be adding the logic to check for cache hit/miss eventually.

```
 <interceptFrom>
        <log message="Intercepted Route" />
  </interceptFrom>
```

I am loading them using the below method,

```
List<InterceptFromDefinition> intDefns=getInterceptDefinitions("Intercept.xml");
```

I also set them to the routes.

```
routes.setInterceptFroms(intDefns);
```

I get the error as below,

```
2016-10-08 22:13:19.711 ERROR 6004 --- [           main] com.demo.composite.util.CamelUtil        : Exception reading configuration files:javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"", local:"interceptFrom"). Expected elements are <{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}aggregate>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}aop>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}avro>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}barcode>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}base64>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}batch-config>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}bean>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}beanio>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}bindy>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}boon>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}castor>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}choice>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}circuitBreaker>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}constant>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}contextScan>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}convertBodyTo>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}crypto>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}csv>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}customDataFormat>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}customLoadBalancer>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}dataFormats>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}delay>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}delete>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}description>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}doCatch>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}doFinally>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}doTry>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}dynamicRouter>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}el>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}enrich>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}exchangeProperty>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}expression>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}expressionDefinition>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}failover>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}filter>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}flatpack>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}from>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}get>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}groovy>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}gzip>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}head>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}header>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}hessian>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}hl7>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}ical>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}idempotentConsumer>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}inOnly>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}inOut>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}intercept>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}interceptFrom>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}interceptSendToEndpoint>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}jacksonxml>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}javaScript>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}jaxb>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}jibx>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}json>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}jsonpath>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}jxpath>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}language>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}loadBalance>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}log>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}loop>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}lzf>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}marshal>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}method>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}mime-multipart>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}multicast>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}mvel>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}ognl>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}onCompletion>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}onException>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}optimisticLockRetryPolicy>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}options>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}otherwise>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}packageScan>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}param>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}patch>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}pgp>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}php>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}pipeline>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}policy>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}pollEnrich>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}post>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}process>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}properties>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}property>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}protobuf>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}put>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}python>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}random>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}recipientList>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}redeliveryPolicy>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}ref>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}removeHeader>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}removeHeaders>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}removeProperties>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}removeProperty>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}resequence>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}responseHeader>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}responseMessage>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}rest>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}restBinding>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}restConfiguration>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}restContextRef>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}restProperty>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}rests>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}rollback>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}roundRobin>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}route>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}routeBuilder>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}routeContextRef>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}routes>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}routingSlip>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}rss>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}ruby>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}sample>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}script>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}secureXML>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}serialization>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}setBody>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}setExchangePattern>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}setFaultBody>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}setHeader>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}setOutHeader>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}setProperty>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}simple>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}soapjaxb>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}sort>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}spel>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}split>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}sql>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}sticky>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}stop>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}stream-config>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}string>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}syslog>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}tarfile>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}terser>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}threadPoolProfile>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}threads>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}throttle>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}throwException>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}tidyMarkup>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}to>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}toD>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}tokenize>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}topic>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}transacted>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}transform>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}univocity-csv>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}univocity-fixed>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}univocity-header>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}univocity-tsv>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}unmarshal>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}validate>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}verb>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}vtdxml>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}weighted>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}when>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}wireTap>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}xmlBeans>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}xmljson>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}xmlrpc>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}xpath>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}xquery>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}xstream>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}xtokenize>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}yaml>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}zip>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}zipFile>
javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"", local:"interceptFrom"). Expected elements are <{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}aggregate>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}aop>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}avro>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}barcode>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}base64>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}batch-config>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}bean>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}beanio>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}bindy>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}boon>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}castor>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}choice>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}circuitBreaker>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}constant>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}contextScan>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}convertBodyTo>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}crypto>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}csv>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}customDataFormat>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}customLoadBalancer>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}dataFormats>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}delay>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}delete>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}description>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}doCatch>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}doFinally>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}doTry>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}dynamicRouter>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}el>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}enrich>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}exchangeProperty>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}expression>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}expressionDefinition>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}failover>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}filter>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}flatpack>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}from>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}get>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}groovy>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}gzip>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}head>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}header>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}hessian>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}hl7>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}ical>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}idempotentConsumer>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}inOnly>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}inOut>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}intercept>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}interceptFrom>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}interceptSendToEndpoint>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}jacksonxml>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}javaScript>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}jaxb>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}jibx>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}json>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}jsonpath>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}jxpath>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}language>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}loadBalance>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}log>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}loop>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}lzf>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}marshal>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}method>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}mime-multipart>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}multicast>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}mvel>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}ognl>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}onCompletion>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}onException>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}optimisticLockRetryPolicy>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}options>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}otherwise>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}packageScan>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}param>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}patch>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}pgp>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}php>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}pipeline>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}policy>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}pollEnrich>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}post>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}process>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}properties>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}property>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}protobuf>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}put>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}python>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}random>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}recipientList>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}redeliveryPolicy>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}ref>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}removeHeader>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}removeHeaders>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}removeProperties>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}removeProperty>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}resequence>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}responseHeader>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}responseMessage>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}rest>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}restBinding>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}restConfiguration>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}restContextRef>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}restProperty>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}rests>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}rollback>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}roundRobin>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}route>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}routeBuilder>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}routeContextRef>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}routes>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}routingSlip>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}rss>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}ruby>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}sample>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}script>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}secureXML>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}serialization>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}setBody>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}setExchangePattern>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}setFaultBody>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}setHeader>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}setOutHeader>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}setProperty>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}simple>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}soapjaxb>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}sort>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}spel>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}split>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}sql>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}sticky>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}stop>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}stream-config>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}string>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}syslog>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}tarfile>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}terser>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}threadPoolProfile>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}threads>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}throttle>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}throwException>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}tidyMarkup>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}to>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}toD>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}tokenize>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}topic>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}transacted>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}transform>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}univocity-csv>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}univocity-fixed>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}univocity-header>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}univocity-tsv>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}unmarshal>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}validate>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}verb>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}vtdxml>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}weighted>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}when>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}wireTap>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}xmlBeans>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}xmljson>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}xmlrpc>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}xpath>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}xquery>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}xstream>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}xtokenize>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}yaml>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}zip>,<{http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring}zipFile>
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.handleEvent(UnmarshallingContext.java:740)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.reportError(Loader.java:262)
```

Probably I need to wrap the interceptFrom using a element similar to the way I wrapped the Rest and RouteDefinitions. But, not sure how.
I am not sure if I am doing it the correct way. 
Can somehow help me on this.

Also, I see there is a InterceptStrategy which can be set to the camelcontext.

Is there a way I can use that to do AOP like processsing for my routes  by applying the caching concern instead of InterceptFrom.

Also, my Camel Application is based on Spring Boot, so is there any feature in Spring Boot which I can use to intercept the route calls.

I have added the sample project which I had created to load my routes and apiroutes in this repo using XML files. Similarly, I would want to apply the cross cutting concern of caching using interceptors so that they do not mix with route logic. I am looking for a way to use the interceptFrom camel feature so that I can intercept every message to a route and handle them accordingly. I am not sure how to load the interceptors or how to have them linked with the routes.

https://github.com/sri420/compositerepo/tree/master/CompositeApplication

I have currently removed the code which I had added to load the interceptors because of namespace error. Once, I get the correct approach of the solution I will add the same accordingly.

Comment: Any particular reason you have an xml file just for loading intercepts? Why not just put in together with the rest of your camelcontext syntax?

Comment: I want the interceptor logic to be common across all routes in my application. So, rather than making it a part of every routes I want that to be separated out, if at all possible. Just as I have separated out the routes and also the rest api routes for my application I wanted to separate out the common concern of interceptors so that they do not mix with the route logic.

Comment: It has to be part of a CamelContext as CamelContext is its parent element in the xsd.

Comment: In my project, I do not have a explicit camel-context.xml, since I am loading the routes and rest-dsl in separate xml files. Is it possible to have a implicit camel-context.xml in my classpath containing only the features which are outside routes and rest dsl like interceptors etc within the camelContext namespace.

Comment: I have not tried that so not sure but your error "javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element" seems to indicate that the element interceptFrom cannot be loaded that way.

Answer (score 0):

Can you give the full Intercept.xml? Seems your Intercept.xml xml file have the wrong namespace, just like

```
<camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
    <!-- intercept incoming messages and route them to the mock:middle1 endpoint
         before we proceed and continue routing from the point of interceptions, that
         is mock:end will be the next target -->
    <interceptFrom>
        <to uri="mock:middle1"/>
    </interceptFrom>

    <!-- here we have a very simple route -->
    <route>
        <from uri="direct:start"/>
        <to uri="mock:end"/>
    </route>
</camelContext>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I currently do not have any namespace in my intercept.xml. Can you let me know what namespace I need to add for interceptFrom. I tried enclosing the interceptFrom element in intercept.xml with camelContext tag by I still get the same error.

Comment: @Shan You can refer to the xml content in my answer above.

Comment: I did try to use xml content you provided but still I have the same error.

Comment: @Shan Please upload your full xml file, you shoule put your "interceptFrom" with the "camelContext" together.